# Windows Installer cannot access network location when installed directories on network drive

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, networking, installation, directory-structure

I have a C++ Windows application built in Visual Studio 2010 with a Setup project to create an .msi that installs fine when users have a local `My Documents` folder, but fails when their `My Documents` folder is located on a network drive.

When installed locally, the installer creates `Project` and `Data` folders in their `My Documents` folder, but when I try to install to system with `My Documents` in a network location, the .msi fails with the `cannot access network location` error message. Looking at the installer log file, it appears that the failure occurs when the installer is creating the property that describes the `Project` and `Data` directories, not when trying to create and populate those directories.

Does anybody have an idea about how I can either avoid, workaround, or recover from this error?

Right now the installation just fails and rolls back for systems with My Documents on networks. Thanks.

From MSI log:

```
"The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2835. The arguments are: ErrorIcon, ErrorDialog, 
Error 1606. Could not access network location \\TOMVEE-W7PC\Users\W8RemoteUserDocs\\eQUEST 3-65 Projects\.
MSI (c) (38:64) [13:13:34:987]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (38:64) [13:13:34:987]: Product: eQUEST 3-65 -- Error 1606. Could not access network location \\TOMVEE-W7PC\Users\W8RemoteUserDocs\\eQUEST 3-65 Projects\.

MSI (c) (38:64) [13:13:34:989]: Note: 1: 1314 2: \\TOMVEE-W7PC\Users\W8RemoteUserDocs\\eQUEST 3-65 Projects\ 
MSI (c) (38:64) [13:13:34:989]: Note: 1: 1606 2: \\TOMVEE-W7PC\Users\W8RemoteUserDocs\\eQUEST 3-65 Projects\ 
MSI (c) (38:64) [13:13:34:989]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (38:BC) [13:13:34:991]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2835:  The control ErrorIcon was not found on dialog ErrorDialog
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2835. The arguments are: ErrorIcon, ErrorDialog, 
Error 1606. Could not access network location \\TOMVEE-W7PC\Users\W8RemoteUserDocs\\eQUEST 3-65 Projects\.
MSI (c) (38:64) [13:13:39:006]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (38:64) [13:13:39:006]: Product: eQUEST 3-65 -- Error 1606. Could not access network location \\TOMVEE-W7PC\Users\W8RemoteUserDocs\\eQUEST 3-65 Projects\.

MSI (c) (38:64) [13:13:39:007]: Note: 1: 1606 2: \\TOMVEE-W7PC\Users\W8RemoteUserDocs\\eQUEST 3-65 Projects\ 
MSI (c) (38:64) [13:13:39:007]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (38:BC) [13:13:39:009]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
```

I don't think the missing Error Icon is relevant, but maybe?

Comment: What happens when you try to navigate directly to the network location that is output in the logs?

Comment: Is this a per-user installation or a per-machine installation?  (If it's a per-machine installation, the installer will be asking for permission to elevate.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem occurred whether installing for just me or all users.

I made a little application to test permissions and update them if inadequate but that still did not fix the problem.

But, along the way, testing manually, I discovered that an extra "\" in the middle of the directory path was causing the problem, like " \TOMVEE-W7PC\Users\W8RemoteUserDocs\eQUEST 3-65 Projects". This extra slash was coming because the [PersonalFolder] used for the folder default location in the setup project properties already generates a "\" and then I was also adding a slash in the property value. This extra slash did not cause problems in local installations, but did cause problems in installations on network locations, probably because the "\" has other meanings in network directories.

So the problem was incorrectly constructed directory path, not permissions. Just posting this answer on the odd chance some other person is struggling with the same problem.

Thanks to responders,
Tom